# Site inaccessible with Cookies turned off in browser

Tags: cookies, html, css

Whenever I access my website with cookies turned off in browser, it redirects me to a google support page that informs me to allow cookies. My website is simple (a blog) HTML and CSS and I store nor ask for any data from the visitors.

I have noticed that whenever I visit the site, it's URL extends by **/?i=1**, **/?i=2** and **/?i=3**  - what's that?

How could I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would actually provide the URL of this site so that others could reproduce your problem. I only can say that I have a site which fits your description (simple, HTML+CSS) and what you describe does not happen there. Thus it is either specific to your site (details missing) or to your browser and plugins (details missing) or to some proxy in your network (details missing).

Answer (score 1):

> My website is simple (a blog) HTML and CSS and I store nor ask for any data from the visitors.

Are you *sure* your site is only HTML+CSS? Your site wouldn't happen to be using some free hosting service that collects and sells user data, would it?

The fact that they're adding URL parameters that have nothing to do with your pages (the `/?i=1`), and that you get redirected to some help page that's not yours if you disable cookies strongly suggest that there's more going on here than just your HTML+CSS. Likely their webserver is processing the incoming requests, stripping off the user tracking information, and then serving your HTML+CSS content.

> How could I prevent this behaviour?

Change hosting providers to someone less sketchy.

Comment: Yes, it must be the hosting provider that is causing this.